# Webkit Local storage limitations and options

Tags: ipad, html, webkit, local-storage

I am researching the best way to implement a local storage html5/js (offline) solution to store web application data.

A few concerns I have:

1. How much can you store? And does this vary based on the device? Ie.
   iPad or iPad 2.
2. What kind of wrappers can you utilize to CRUD the data?
3. With over 3000 items and pictures, what will be the best way to
   store images?

So basically I have a ton of data that I need to be able to store on an offline webkit device and I'm looking for the best solution to manage all of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three thousand items (especially if many of the items are photos) is a lot for offline storage the way devices currently handle it.

Check these resources for how to handle HTML5 offline storage...

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/

Also see the latest file handling API stuff in Google Chrome.  Truly awesome "what's coming" resource.
http://www.htmlfivewow.com